# Remove an observer in Ember component

Tags: ember.js

I want to remove a observer I registered at a current point. Say I got following component:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    observeSomeProp: function() {
        //do something 
    }.observes('someProp'),

    obserOtherProp: function() {
       if( condition ) {
           //remove observeSomeProp
       }
    }.observes('otherProp')  
});
```

I am reading the docs, the [removeObserver](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Observable.html#method_removeObserver) function needs three arguments 'key', 'target' and 'method'. I suppose the 'method' argument would be `observeSomeProp` for given example, but what about the 'key' and 'target'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right about the 'method' param, but I don't think you can remove an observer that's hardcoded into the component like that (as far as I've read...). As for the others, the 'key' would be the property you want to watch, so 'someProp', and the 'target' would be the view/component space you're working in, so just `this` in your case.

Try adding your observers to [willInsertElement](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html#event_willInsertElement) and removing them in [willDestroyElement](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html#event_willDestroyElement):

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  willInsertElement: function () {
    var self = this;

    // Add observers
    self.addObserver('self.someProp', self, self.propObserver);
    self.addObserver('self.otherProp', self, self.otherPropObserver);

    return self.super();
  },

  propObserver: function () {
    //Do something
  },

  otherPropObserver: function () {
    //Do something else
    if( condition ) {
      //remove propObserver
      var self = this;
      this.removeAnObserver('self.someProp', self, self.propObserver);
    }
  },

  // This is the method that's removing all the observers
  removeAnObserver: function (key, target, method) {
    // Remove observer
    self.removeObserver(key, target, method);
  },

  willDestroyElement: function () {
    var self = this;

    //remove any observers you set in willInsertElement
    this.removeAnObserver('self.someProp', self, self.propObserver);
    this.removeAnObserver('self.otherProp', self, self.otherPropObserver);
  }
});
```

It may look like a lot more code, but `willInsertElement` and `willDestroyElement` can be used for a lot of other stuff in your component, and you can optimize with mixins if you feel it getting too crowded.